# Pass a variable from AMPscript block to Client side JS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript, html, variable

I have an index.html file with the following structure:

```
%%[
 SET @contactId = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")
]%%

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to pass the @contactId from the AMPscrip block to the script block?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_utilitiesVariableGetValue.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just print the ampscript variable where you normally set a client-side javascript variable. In the below example, I set the cid to the contactId ampscript you already declare in the top:

```
%%[
 SET @contactId = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")
]%%

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    var cid = "%%=v(@contactId)=%%";
    console.log(cid);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, Lukas. Worked like a charm. :)